# Send Facebook image url as parameter

Tags: php, facebook

Facebook image url for user profile looks like

```
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c26.26.321.321/s50x50/1004031_160695494109373_202362495_n.jpg?oh=bc24275f3c0b63adcd7f2
```

I want to send this url in request to server

```
$FBImageUrl = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c26.26.321.321/s50x50/1004031_160695494109373_202362495_n.jpg?oh=bc24275f3c0b63adcd7f2";
$postString = "http://example.com/script.php?img_url=" . FBImageUrl;
```

But what will happen if this url have question mark inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `urlencode()`

```
$FBImageUrl = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c26.26.321.321/s50x50/1004031_160695494109373_202362495_n.jpg?oh=bc24275f3c0b63adcd7f2";
$postString = "http://example.com/script.php?img_url=".urlencode($FBImageUrl) ;
```

In your script.php

```
$img_url = urldecode($_GET['img_url']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `base64_encode` & `base64_decode`. Also for security reasons image URL wont be visible in the address bar.

```
$FBImageUrl = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/c26.26.321.321/s50x50/1004031_160695494109373_202362495_n.jpg?oh=bc24275f3c0b63adcd7f2";
$base64Url = base64_encode($FBImageUrl);
$postString = "http://example.com/script.php?img_url=" . $base64Url;
```

Receiver you can decode it

```
$fbUrl = base64_decode($_GET['img_url']);
```